# Update Primary Index for Table with Identity Column

Tags: sql, primary-key, teradata, alter

Is it possible to change the Unique Primary Index / Primary Index of a Teradata table which contains existing data and has an identity column? What would be the best way to do it while preserving the values currently used in the identity column?

Here is the current table DDL:

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE AUDIT.AUDIT_DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR, NO FALLBACK,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO(
      DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR_KEY INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(
            START WITH 1
            INCREMENT BY 1
            MINVALUE -2147483647
            MAXVALUE 2147483647
            NO CYCLE)
      ,DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL
      ,DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(1000) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL
      ,DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR_TYPE_KEY INTEGER
      ,DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR_DEFAULT_BATCH_OWNER VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL
      ,DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR_EXECUTION_ORDER INTEGER NOT NULL
      ,FLAG_DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR_ACTIVE VARCHAR(12) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL DEFAULT 'INACTIVE'
      ,SCRIPT_NAME VARCHAR(500) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL
      ,FUNCTION_NAME VARCHAR(500) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL
      ,ALERT_THRESHOLD VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL
      ,ALERT_DISTRIBUTION_LIST VARCHAR(1000) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL
      ,SUBJECT_AREA_KEY SMALLINT NOT NULL
      ,CREATION_DATE TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL
      ,LAST_UPDATE TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL
      ,AUDIT_PROCESS_KEY INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
      ,SPACE_ID VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ND'
,FOREIGN KEY ( DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR_TYPE_KEY ) REFERENCES WITH NO CHECK OPTION AUDIT.AUDIT_DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR_TYPE ( DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR_TYPE_KEY )
,FOREIGN KEY ( AUDIT_PROCESS_KEY ) REFERENCES WITH NO CHECK OPTION AUDIT.AUDIT_PROCESS ( AUDIT_PROCESS_KEY )
,FOREIGN KEY ( SUBJECT_AREA_KEY ) REFERENCES WITH NO CHECK OPTION EDW.DIM_SUBJECT_AREA ( SUBJECT_AREA_KEY )
)
UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX UPI_AUDIT_DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR ( DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR_KEY );
```

I would like to change it to:

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE AUDIT.AUDIT_DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR, NO FALLBACK,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO(
      DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR_KEY INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(
            START WITH 1
            INCREMENT BY 1
            MINVALUE -2147483647
            MAXVALUE 2147483647
            NO CYCLE)
      ,DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL
      ,DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(1000) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL
      ,DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR_TYPE_KEY INTEGER
      ,DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR_DEFAULT_BATCH_OWNER VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL
      ,DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR_EXECUTION_ORDER INTEGER NOT NULL
      ,FLAG_DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR_ACTIVE VARCHAR(12) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL DEFAULT 'INACTIVE'
      ,SCRIPT_NAME VARCHAR(500) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL
      ,FUNCTION_NAME VARCHAR(500) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL
      ,ALERT_THRESHOLD VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL
      ,ALERT_DISTRIBUTION_LIST VARCHAR(1000) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL
      ,SUBJECT_AREA_KEY SMALLINT NOT NULL
      ,CREATION_DATE TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL
      ,LAST_UPDATE TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL
      ,AUDIT_PROCESS_KEY INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
      ,SPACE_ID VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ND'
,FOREIGN KEY ( DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR_TYPE_KEY ) REFERENCES WITH NO CHECK OPTION AUDIT.AUDIT_DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR_TYPE ( DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR_TYPE_KEY )
,FOREIGN KEY ( AUDIT_PROCESS_KEY ) REFERENCES WITH NO CHECK OPTION AUDIT.AUDIT_PROCESS ( AUDIT_PROCESS_KEY )
,FOREIGN KEY ( SUBJECT_AREA_KEY ) REFERENCES WITH NO CHECK OPTION EDW.DIM_SUBJECT_AREA ( SUBJECT_AREA_KEY )
)
UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX UPI_AUDIT_DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR ( DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR, SPACE_ID );
```

Comment: What do you mean with "change the Primary Index"? What is the table structure and what is the desire structure? Could you elaborate more?

Comment: You cannot alter the PI on a table with data in it.  You have to move it to a new table.

Comment: The problem is if I move data to another table and then reinsert it into the new table with the new UPI, the values in the identity column will change.

Comment: There's aboslutely no reason to add a 2nd column to an already unique PI.

Comment: The thing is values in in `DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR` are not unique. Wouldn't that be an issue? On the other side the combination of `DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR` and `SPACE_ID` is unique.

Comment: Ups, sorry, I didn't see that it's a different column. What column(s) are actually used in WHERE/JOIN? If it's the combination of `DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR, SPACE_ID` why it's not the PI already? If it's `DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR_KEY` why do you want to change it.

Comment: The table design and usages evolved over time. We initially used DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR_KEY as a UPI because it’s what we use in joins but later on we figured out we very often use DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR and SPACE_ID in the where clause and that would be more performant (data is exposed via a REST API)

Comment: @dnoeth if I can’t change the PI, would you say adding these columns as USI would be useful?

Comment: When both `DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR, SPACE_ID` are used in combination in WHERE a USI would be fine. When there are two candidates for PI, one is used more in joins and the other in Where the Join one should be PI (as the optinizer is hardly using SIs for joins).

Comment: @dnoeth don't you want to post your comment in an answer. I would accept it.